# Which option (of the given notations) is preferred and is more clear to the reader?

Tags: notation, terminology

I have an expression like this

$$  f(x)=\pm 2x (6\frac {a^3}6+b-c x^{5-y}) \qquad (1) $$

I have two questions:

> 1. I want to use the function $f(x)$ in the text with its positive sign; should I use the term "function $f(x)$ with upper sign in (1)" or "function $f(x)$ with plus sign in (1)"?

> 2. Is it OK if instead of the point mentioned in the first question, I use

$$ f^{\pm}(x)=\pm 2x (6\frac {a^3}6+b-c x^{5-y}) \qquad (1) $$

> and then simply refer to $f^+(x)$ in the text?

Which option is preferred and is more clear to the reader?

Comment: The latter notation is clear to me, although I would probably use subscripts $f_{\pm}$ to leave space for exponents, derivative symbols, etc.

Comment: In the context of the square root, e.g., $y^2=x$, or $y=\pm\sqrt{x}$, the positive root is called the *principal square root*. I suppose that convention could hold here as well.

Comment: @SammyBlack Thank you for the comment. As for your suggestion to put $\pm$ at the bottom does not work in my case since indeed my function already has it, it is like $f_{a,b}$, and now, I want to use the notation $f_{a,b}^{\pm}$. Fortunately, I do not need derivatives of this function.

Comment: Sure. Remember: the notation works for you, not the other way around. As long as you clearly explain what the symbols mean, you're good to go.

Comment: I'd use #2 (with subscript instead of superscript as Sammy mentions).  But to be safe you can include a bit of English: "We will use a subscript to indicate the choice of sign on the coefficient, setting $$f_{\pm}(x)=\pm 2x (6\frac {a^3}6+b-c x^{5-y}).$$

Comment: @JairTaylor Thanks for the explanations.